# In Inverse Propensity Score Weighting, is it possible to find an explicit solution to the estimator by way of Jacobians?

Tags: bayesian, multiple-regression, causality

In IPSW, a propensity score model is specified (usually an inverse logit) on a set of covariates, then from that, we use Weighted Least Squares regression to obtain the estimates. However, I am wondering how the estimator is obtained this way.

In order to find the estimator, wouldn't we have to rely on Jacobian
s to find the transformation from the propensity score into the Weighted Least Squares estimator when we compute the expectation? How is the estimator found without doing this? Thanks.

Comment: The IPSW, you simply divide each treated outcome by its PS and each control outcomes by its 1-PS, and then calculate the difference in means to get the average treatment effect. The intuition is that a unit with a very high probability of treatment gets a weight close to 1, because we almost always observe that unit – there is no need to scale up its outcome. In contrast, a unit with a probability of treatment of 0.1 gets its outcome divided by 0.1 to reflect the fact that we observe only 1 in 10 of such units as treated units.

Comment: However, you must divide by the total sample size, rather than sample size of each group in calculating the means.

Comment: I see, so if I were to derive out the expectation of the difference in means would that be another estimator? what would that be estimating?

Comment: This estimates the average treatment effect. There's also a similar formula for the ATE on the Treated.

Comment: Got it, I just had one more question about the possibility of closing the form. Suppose my covariates $X_i$ are all iid normal, with my propensity score $p_i = logit(X_i)$, and with my outcomes $Y_i \sim N(X_i + \tau Z_i, \sigma^2)$ where $Z_i \sim Bern(p_i)$. Under this case is there a way to derive in closed form the estimator of $\tau$ by using the equation $\hat{\tau} = (X^TWX)^{-1}X^TWY$ and $W_i = diag(p_i)$? Is there a way I can "send" the distribution of $p_i$ as a transformation of normal random variables into $W$ and then into $\hat{\tau}$? Thank you!